# Re-render functional component when property of another class changes [MVVM]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mvvm

I'm trying to implement MVVM in React (requirement from the class I'm taking). I'm using functional components for the view and have typescript classes for the ViewModel. My components do not re-render when a property is updated in the ViewModel though.

Here's a simple example for a page that should toggle between a login and sign up form. The setCurrentForm gets called correctly and the value in the ViewModel does update, but it doesn't change the View.

```js
// AuthView.tsx
const AuthView: React.FC = () => {
  const VM = new AuthViewModel();

  let form;
  if (VM.currentForm === FORMS.SignUp) {
    // Toggles the current form between FORMS.SignUp and FORMS.Login
    form = <SignUpForm setCurrentForm={() => VM.setCurrentForm()} />
  } else {
    form = <LoginForm setCurrentForm={() => VM.setCurrentForm()} />
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {/* Sign up card */}
      <div className="mt-12">
        {form}
      </div>
    </Container> 
  );
}
export default AuthView;
```

```js
// AuthViewModel.tsx
export default class AuthViewModel {
  email: string = "";
  password: string = "";
  currentForm: FORMS = FORMS.SignUp;

  setCurrentForm() {
    console.log("Setting form in VM");
    if (this.currentForm === FORMS.SignUp) {
      console.log("Switching to login")
      this.currentForm = FORMS.Login;
    } else if (this.currentForm === FORMS.Login) {
      console.log("Switching to signup")
      this.currentForm = FORMS.SignUp;
    }
  }
}
```

I could force the re-render with a hook by updating an arbitrary value, but I think there's a better way to do this. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missunderstanding how react components re-render, just because you change some property in another object it has no bearing on the component itself, even if it has taken a property from this object.

Hooks are directly connected to the reacts render mechanism and can trigger render cycles, as such you should use something like this:

```js
const AuthView: React.FC = () => {
  // if you don't put this in a state a new VM will be created when the component rerenders
  const [VM] = useState(new AuthViewModel());

  useEffect(() => {
    // Maybe some handler code is needed?
  }, VM.currentForm);

  let form;
  if (VM.currentForm === FORMS.SignUp) {
    // Toggles the current form between FORMS.SignUp and FORMS.Login
    form = <SignUpForm setCurrentForm={() => VM.setCurrentForm()} />
  } else {
    form = <LoginForm setCurrentForm={() => VM.setCurrentForm()} />
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {/* Sign up card */}
      <div className="mt-12">
        {form}
      </div>
    </Container> 
  );
}
export default AuthView;
```

I've never tried to observe a nested property via a hook, so not 100% this works.

EDIT: it doesn't work, but it makes sense, the rendering call gets triggered when you actually call the set function of the useState hook, not really sure how to implement this pattern with hooks and without something like redux or mobx, but here is my best approach:

```js
class AuthViewModel() {

  constructor(public readonly currentForm = 'LOGIN');

  public setCurrentForm = () => {
    if(this.currentForm === 'LOGIN')
      return new AuthViewModel('SIGNUP')
    else
      return new AuthViewModel(); // will default to login
  }
}
```

and then the component

```js
const AuthView: React.FC = () => {
  // if you don't put this in a state a new VM will be created when the component rerenders
  const [VM, setVM] = useState(new AuthViewModel());

  let form;
  if (VM.currentForm === FORMS.SignUp) {
    // Toggles the current form between FORMS.SignUp and FORMS.Login
    form = <SignUpForm setCurrentForm={() => setVM(VM.setCurrentForm())} />
  } else {
    form = <LoginForm setCurrentForm={() => setVM(VM.setCurrentForm())} />
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {/* Sign up card */}
      <div className="mt-12">
        {form}
      </div>
    </Container> 
  );
}

export default AuthView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly this doesn't work. I understand that normally updating state in a component will update the component (with setState or useState).

Comment: updated the answer :) not sure if this is the pattern you want though, basically the VM is a shallow object in order to hook into the render cycle, you might want to look into redux or mobx and figure out a way to tell react to re-render the component when their state changes

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking I'll need to grab something like mobx to have the view observe the view model. Thank you!

Comment: don't forget to upvote if you found the answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have here doesn't feel very *React*. For starters, I've only rarely seen classes used outside of class-based components. I'm just going to spitball a different solution here that might not exactly match what you need, but hopefully gets you going in a correct direction.

```
const Authenticate: FC = props => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<"login" | "create">("login");

  return (
    <div>
      {mode === "login" && <Login onLogin={({email, password}) => {/*login handler logic*/}}/>}
      {mode === "create" && <CreateAccount onCreate={({email, password}) => {/*create handler logic*/}}/>}

      <button 
        disabled={mode === "login"} 
        onClick={() => setMode("login")}
      >
        login
      </button>
      <button 
        disabled={mode === "create"} 
        onClick={() => setMode("create")}
      >
        sign up
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Login: FC<{onLogin: ({email: string, password: string}) => any}> = props => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { onLogin } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => onLogin({email, password})}>
      <input value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}

const CreateAccount: FC<{onCreate: ({email: string, password: string}) => any}> = props => {
  return (
    <div>... similar to <Login/> ... </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I understand it's not very react-like. I wouldn't normally build an application like this. I would use hooks and keep state and login within the actual component, but I have to use MVVM or MVP for the class I'm taking, which necessitates moving most of the logic out of my functional components and having them rely on the ViewModel class.

Comment: It's a design patterns class. The default option was to do it in Android. I work in React, so I thought it would save me a lot of time, but the TA's (with limited React experience) have added more and more constraints to the students choosing to not use Android.